# Catalina Safari "Proxy Automatic Configuration" (PAC) is not used

Tags: network, safari, proxy

Running Catalina (10.15.6) My SOCKS5 proxy is a `DynamicForward`declared port on a ssh session.

My pac file is ultra simple and tested good using online test tools, as well as Chrome which uses the OS's PAC setting.

To eliminate a filesystem sandbox issue, I host the PAC file using a python SimpleHTTPServer. I can see the file being downloaded when I configure it in Network prefs, as well as when I launch chrome and safari.

For some reason, Safari doesn't use my proxy. If I configure the proxy address and port directly under "Proxy" in network prefs, safari uses it fine.

Any clues or troubleshooting suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I learned:

- Safari requires `SOCKS localhost...` not `SOCK5 localhost...`, but Chrome requires `SOCKS5 localhost...` So my pac file returns `'SOCKS5 localhost:12345;SOCKS localhost:12345'`
- Apps now being [very sandboxed](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html), you cannot use `file:///Some/Path/proxy.pac` that will be readable by all apps requiring the proxy config. World readable areas are now read-only in macOS.
- If your pac file is not sensitive, save yourself the hassle of running an http server and host your file on some server somewhere. I used a [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com) file. Make sure you make it public and use the "raw" link to copy/paste into macOS' "Proxy Automatic configuration" URL.